# Principle of working of a transformer

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-current, electromagnetic-induction

What is the principle of working of transformers?

1. Magnetic effects of current
2. Mutual induction
3. Self induction
4. Chemical effects of current

I know that Mutual induction is the right answer, but isn't magnetic effects of current also a correct answer?

In a transformer, ac current flows in the primary coil, which produces changing magnetic field, which in turn induces current in the secondary coil.

So, is magnetic effects of current also an acceptable answer to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're absolutely right, and you know the answer is mutual induction, but of course it does involve magnetic effects of the current so I assume there would be some marks given for that answer, perhaps half of those given for mutual induction.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you are right, nut mutual induction is a more specific form of magnetic effect on electric current. When the two coils are placed near to each each other, there flux gets linked, we get the formula

> Flux = Mutual induction * Current